# Different output with pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

Why do I get different output with `tesseract` and `pytesseract`?
In tesseract:

```
tesseract t10.tiff output -1 eng
```

In python

```
ocr_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='-psm 3').
```

Comment: What output do you get? What if you set same psm mode for tesseract cmd?

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have change to same psm mode, but no different. In  tesseract when I use 1- eng  output is P. IVA “05307630961UNICREDIT, with eng+deu output is IVA IT05307630961UNICREDIT. ocr_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')  output is IVA ÔÇØ05307630961

Comment: If I change ocr_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng+deu') I get the same output  IVA ÔÇØ05307630961. The orginaltext is IVA IT05307630961 UNICREDIT.

Comment: Just a note that `config` parameter is for filename of config file, not command line parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at pytesseract.run_tesseract(), you will see that pytesseract runs a subprocess that creates another .PNG file, THEN run tesseract subprocess on that image. I put a python debugger right after the file is created and tried copying the file on disk for inspection. Turned out that the file color profile is different from the original image. Further, the new image has 3 color channels while the original image has an alpha channel. Try running tesseract from command line on this new image and you'll get the same result you get from running pytesseract on the original image.[Generated PNG vs Original png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9T9r.png)